# Selecting random value (array) from dictionary

Tags: swift

I am just starting to learn Swift and cannot seem to figure out how to select a random array from Swift without it changing each click for the concentration game. Essentially, my goal is to select a random value, which is an array, from a dictionary, and use it for the rest of the run. The issue I am running into, is that my random index, `randomThemeIndex` is changing each click, and does not keep the same theme for all of the cards in the game. So it is selecting various elements from each value in the dictionary, and not just one value/array. Here is what I have thus far:

```
var themeChoices = ["halloween": ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
                    "animals": ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
                    "faces": ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
                    "nature": ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "❄️", ""],
                    "food": ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
                    "sports": ["⚽️", "", "", "", "", "⛳️", "", "", "‍♀️", "", "️"]]

var emoji = [Int:String]()


func emoji(for card: Card) -> String {
    let themeCount = themeChoices.count
    let randomThemeIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(themeCount)))
    print(randomThemeIndex)
    var randomTheme = Array(themeChoices.values)[randomThemeIndex]
    if emoji[card.identifier] == nil, randomTheme.count > 0 {
        let randomCardIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(randomTheme.count - 1)))
        emoji[card.identifier] = randomTheme.remove(at: randomCardIndex)
    }
    return emoji[card.identifier] ?? "?"
}
```

Comment: where is your Card declaration

Comment: You are generating a new random number each time you call this method. You need to select a random theme somewhere else that you only call once and then use that theme in this function.

Comment: emoji[card.identifier]?  It's no offense, but you should go back to books.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to select a new random array each time you call `emoji(for:)`, right? So you need to store the active array index somewhere and use it each time.

Instead of this:

```
func emoji(for card: Card) -> String {
    let themeCount = themeChoices.count
    let randomThemeIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(themeCount)))
```

Try like this:

```
func emoji(for card: Card, inTheme randomThemeIndex: Int) -> String {
    // remove those two lines and keep the rest
```

Now you'll need to add the theme index, so instead of calling `emoji(for: card)`, you'd call `emoji(for: card, inTheme: themeIndex)`.

You will also need to store the theme index somewhere. I don't know where you should do that because there isn't enough code in your example, but it may look like this:

```
lazy var themeIndex: Int = {
    let themeCount = themeChoices.count
    return Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(themeCount)))
}()
```

Which you could then access as `self.themeIndex`.

¯_(ツ)_/¯